# how to add the text record in the bonjour dns-sd

Tags: bonjour, mdns, dns-sd

I am able to register  a service using bonjour dns-sd on my linux pc.

```
$dns-sd -P SMARTCAM _ftp._tcp. .  80 AIR 14.99.8.77
```

Now I am unable to add text record with registration. Can some body tell me how to add the text record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$dns-sd -P SMARTCAM _ftp._tcp. . 80 air.local 14.99.8.77 "u=test" "path=/pub"
```

I'm just not sure about the `.local` part of the name, compared to the apparently non-local IP address. What are you trying to do, exactly? I'd normally expect to see this registering a local IP address, e.g.:

```
$dns-sd -P SMARTCAM _ftp._tcp. . 80 air.local 10.1.1.58 "u=test" "path=/pub"
```

If you want to register a sub-type, for example, a printer, then you add the sub-type name after the main type name, comma-separated (thanks to [this post](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/blog/2011/01/02/0017) for showing how to do it):

```
$dns-sd -P "Test Print" _http._tcp,_printer . 8080 air.local 10.1.1.58 "path=whatever"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information I am able to add the text record  . I want to register the subtypes . example I have some strange requirement for the my application , in the application protocol names of the bonjour service registarion I need to do avoid the “_” for the first name . "_printer._sub._http._tcp." for example in the above name I need to remove the _ from the printer and make it “printer._sub._http._tcp." . ,, is it possible to  do with mdns responder ..

Comment: @Suru: That sounds like a very strange "requirement", and as far as I know, it is contrary to the DNS-SD specification.

Comment: Hi,  Zero Configuration Networking by Cheshire & Steinberg [O'Reilly 2006] page 65 gives an example of open._sub._mynetgame._tcp.  and says that 
The underscore at the beginning of the subtype is not a requirement.  It's optional.  Stylistically you might choose to use an underscore for consistency with the service type, but you don't have to as long as you define the subtype as including or not including an underscore, and then stick with it.... but that is not discussed about how to register without underscore ... any input on the same to register the service with out underscore .

Comment: *"I'm just not sure about the `.local` part of the name"*. Actually, it should be *`air.local.`* (with added **`.`** at the end). The *"non-local IP address"* is because the ***`-P`*** (for proxy) parameter indeed registers a remote IP address and a remote services as a proxy announcement, so as to make local clients easily discover the remote services... (You may want to update your answer accordingly...)